# How to switch to discrete graphics with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: graphics, bios, acpi

I'm having trouble switching to the discrete graphics on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS in order to try to solve ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol at boot.

My system:

Model: HP ProBook 4545s
CPU: AMD® A4-4300m apu with radeon(tm) hd graphics × 2
Memory: 16GB
Graphics card: AMD® Aruba
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS